# How to implement Quicksort in C with pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I am currently translating my Java quicksort program into C, but I am unsure if I am using pointers correctly. As far as I know I believe I am using them correctly in my partition method or at least my syntax is correct -- I am not getting any errors. I am; however, getting the same array as my result. My current program is

```
' 
// quickSort.c
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #
      void swap(int *a, int *b);
      void quickSort( int[], int, int);
      int partition( int*, int, int);
      int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      {
        int a[] = {2, 6, 5, 1}; 
        int i;
       // int arrlength = sizeof(a); WRONG
        int arrlength = 4; 
        printf("\n\nUnsorted array is:  ");
        for(i = 0; i < arrlength; ++i)
            printf(" %d ", a[i]);

        //array, 0, length 
        quickSort( a, 0, arrlength);

        printf("\n\nSorted array is:  ");
        for(i = 0; i < arrlength; ++i)
            printf(" %d ", a[i]);
        printf("\n\n");

      }


      // char yo[] = "Hello"; 
      // &yo[0] = will be equivalent to = Hello &yo[0] points to variable yo[0]

      //array, Leftmost position, Rightmost position
      void quickSort( int a[], int L, int R)
      {
         int k;

         if( R <= L){
          return;
         }
          k = partition( a, L, R);
          quickSort( a, L, k); // Sort left half of partitioned array
          quickSort( a, k+1, R);  // Sort right half of partitioned array
      }




      // L= leftmost position in the array 
      // R= rightmost position in the array 
      // int *a = pointer to array we are sorting 

      int partition(int a[], int L, int R) {

       // [2   , 6 , 5 , 1] 
       //  |             |
       //  |             |   once the two pointers cross we exist the while loop. 
       //  |             |
       //  S             B=4 & p[B]=1

      int pivot; 
      int help; 
      int S; 
      int B; 
      S = L;  //S = current Leftmost position
      B = R-1;//B = rightmost position
      pivot = a[R-1];     //rightmost number in array
      int *pop; 
      pop = &a[B]; //pop points to address of array 
      //*pop is the actual variable in the address a[B]

      while(B > S) {//as long as the two pointers don't cross you continue
        if(a[B-1] > pivot){   //move to the right of the pivot 
          pop = &a[B-1]; 
          B--; 
        }
        else {
          swap(&a[B-1], &a[S]);// move to left of the pivot 
          S++; 
        }
      }

        pop = &pivot;  // Put pivot in the "hole" 
        return B;  //return the position of the pivot

      }

      void swap(int *a, int *b){
        int temp; 
        temp = *a; 
        *a = *b; 
        *b = temp; 
      }


      // Unsorted array is:   2  6  5  1 

      // Sorted array is:   2  6  5  1 

      // First partition: 
      // pivot = 1; 
      // 2,6,5,5
      // 2,6,6,5
      // 2,2,6,5
      // escape while loop
      // 1,2,6,5

 '
```

In case anyone wants to see my Java program, this is it: 
'
        import java.util.Arrays;

```
    public class AltSorts {

     public static void QuickSort( double[] a, int L, int R ){
         int k;
         if ( R <= L){ 
             return;
            }   
         k = partition( a, L, R );

        QuickSort( a, L, k );   // Sort left half of partitioned array
        QuickSort( a, k+1, R); // Sort right half of partitioned array

    }

     public static int partition( double[] a, int L, int R )
     {
        double   pivot;
        double   help;
        int      S;
        int     B;
    /**
     [2     ,   6   ,   5   ,   1] 
      |                         |
      |                         |       once the two pointers cross we exist the while loop. 
      |                         |
      S                         B=4 & p[B]=1
     * */
        S = L;  //S = current Leftmost position
        B   = R-1;//B = rightmost position
        pivot = a[R-1];     //rightmost number in array

        while ( B > S )//as long as the two pointers don't cross you continue
        {
             if ( a[B -1] > pivot ){          //move to the right of the pivot 
              a[B] = a[B -1];
              B--;
         }
           else

           {  
               help = a[B -1]; // move to left of the pivot 
               a[B -1] = a[S];
               a[S] = help;
               S++;
           }
        }
        a[B] = pivot;   // Put pivot in the "hole" 
        return B; //return the position of the pivot
     }
     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
         double[] x = {2, 6, 5, 1}; 
        System.out.println("Before sort:    " + Arrays.toString(x) + "\n" );  

        QuickSort( x, 0, x.length );     // Quick sort

        System.out.println("\nAfter sort:     " + Arrays.toString(x) );
     }
    }
```

'

Comment: please fix your indent. i read both `partition` functions in C and Java, they are wrong. specifically, in your else case, why would i swap if `a[S]` is smaller than pivot anyway? and a tiny style tip is, if your `B` will have more case to  be subtracted by 1 than not to be, why don't you define it in another way? it's easier to read.

Comment: another bug in your program, is partition returns the position of pivot, so why would you pass the pivot back in the recursive sort? the position of pivot is fixed any way.

Comment: a[B] = pivot; should probably be *pop=pivot;  Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.  C has a sort already and as a learning exercise it's not exactly a 1 to 1 conversion, which it pretty much could be

Comment: and why don't you use the qsort library function?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using a debugger (such as `gdb`)?

Comment: If you're seriously about doing this with pointers, this gets much easier with only *two* arguments: a base address and a length. When recursing into subpartitions the passed-down *base* is adjusted. It honestly makes for a cleaner algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HuStmpHrrr** pointed out a few problems in your source code. And, it was thanks to him that I was able to figure out what you were doing wrong.

The result of your partitioning routine is unbalanced ( take a look a the "pop" and also at the return value of your partition function )

I wrote this code following your implementation ( made a few changes )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/// Function prototypes
void
swap( int *a, int *b );

void
quickSort( int *a, int low, int high );

int
partition( int *a, int low, int high );

int main( int argc, const char * argv[] ) {
    // insert code here...
    int a[] = { 2, 6, 5, 1 };

    quickSort( a, 0, 3 );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) {
        printf( "%d ", a[ i ] );
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/// Function definitions
void
swap( int *a, int *b )
{
    assert( a != NULL );
    assert( b != NULL );

    int temp = *a;
    *a       = *b;
    *b       = temp;
}

void
quickSort( int *a, int low, int high )
{
    assert( a != NULL );

    if ( high <= low ) {
        return;
    }

    int k = partition( a, low, high );
    quickSort( a, low, k - 1 );     /// Sort left part
    quickSort( a, k + 1, high );    /// Sort right part
}

int
partition( int *a, int low, int high )
{
    assert( a != NULL );

    bool flag  = false;
    int  first = low;        /// Left indice
    int  last  = high +1;    /// Right indice
    int  pivot = a[ low ];   /// Partitioning item

    while ( !flag ) {
        while ( a[ ++first ] < pivot ) {   /// Scan left and move
            if ( first == high) flag = true;
        }
        while ( a[ --last ] > pivot ) {    /// Scan right and move
            if ( last == low ) flag  = true;
        }

        if ( first >= last ) {
            flag = true;
        }
        else {
            swap( &a[ first], &a[ last ] );
        }
    }

    swap( &a[ low ], &a[ last ] );

    return last;
}
```

Comment: Your `quicksort` call is using the wrong upper index. Should be `quickSort( a, 0, 3 );`

Comment: Thanks for catching that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// quickSort.c
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #
      void swap(int *a, int *b);
      void quickSort( int *a, int, int);
      int partition( int *a, int, int);
      int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      {
        int a[] = {0, 2, 6, 5, 1}; 
        int i;
       // int arrlength = sizeof(a); WRONG
        int arrlength = 5; 
        printf("\n\nUnsorted array is:  ");
        for(i = 0; i < arrlength; ++i)
            printf(" %d ", a[i]);

        //array, 0, length 
        quickSort( a, 0, arrlength);

        printf("\n\nSorted array is:  ");
        for(i = 0; i < arrlength; ++i)
            printf(" %d ", a[i]);
        printf("\n\n");

      }


      // char yo[] = "Hello"; 
      // &yo[0] = will be equivalent to = Hello &yo[0] points to variable yo[0]

      //array, Leftmost position, Rightmost position
      void quickSort( int *a, int L, int R)
      {
         int k;

         if( R <= L){
          return;
         }
          k = partition( a, L, R);
          quickSort( a, L, k); // Sort left half of partitioned array
          quickSort( a, k+1, R);  // Sort right half of partitioned array
      }




      // L= leftmost position in the array 
      // R= rightmost position in the array 
      // int *a = pointer to array we are sorting 

      int partition(int *a, int L, int R) {

       // [2   , 6 , 5 , 1] 
       //  |             |
       //  |             |   once the two pointers cross we exist the while loop. 
       //  |             |
       //  S             B=4 & p[B]=1

      int pivot; 
      int help; 
      int Small; 
      int Big; 
      Small = L;  //S = current Leftmost position
      Big = R-1;//B = rightmost position
      pivot = a[R-1];     //rightmost number in array


      while(Big > Small) {//as long as the two pointers don't cross you continue
        if(a[Big-1] > pivot){   //move to the right of the pivot 
          swap(&a[Big], &a[Big-1]); //HERE IS THE CHANGE I MADE!!!!!!!!!!!
          Big--; 
        }
        else {
          swap(&a[Big-1], &a[Small]);// move to left of the pivot 
          Small++; 
        }
      }
       //HERE IS THE CHANGE I MADE!!!!!!!!!!!
        //pop
        //pop = &pivot;  // Put pivot in the "hole" 
        return Big;  //return the position of the pivot

      }

      void swap(int *a, int *b){
        int temp; 
        temp = *a; 
        *a = *b; 
        *b = temp; 
      }
```

While your answer is right, it did undo much of my logic. All I had to do was take away the pop = &pivot and just use the swap method on the array when the items were greater than the pivot.